# Using (Shared) Reminders on iPhone - Any Way to Recover?

Tags: iphone, ios, reminders

So, my wife created a Reminders list on her phone and added me.  When I accepted the share and went into it, it wasn't loading the list items, so I deleted the list and she removed the share and readded me.  But now I can't get the list.

If I log into iCloud it says that I've already accepted the share.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your wife needs to recover it from her last backup - then let it share in its own sweet time ;)

Comment: I don't think there is a backup.  But it works fine on her phone.

Comment: Ah, sorry - wasn't reading properly. Maybe if she renames it, or something to make iCloud think it's something different.